# Resolving ARRAYFORMULA() Circular Dependency error

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**Situation**: I have a tab with 2 columns, A & B. A is either blank or contains a dash `-` that I manually add. B is a date.

**Desired behavior**: When I add a dash in column A I’d like the date to increment up 1 day in Col B of the same row. If A is blank then the date should be the same as row above it.

**Current setup**: right now I have a formula that works but I’d like to make it an ARRAYFORMULA (or BYROW, etc.) so I don’t need to drag my existing formula down an arbitrary length and potentially run past it in the future. The formula I’ve entered in `B5` (which produces the desired outcome) and dragged down is:

```
=IF(A5="-",
OFFSET(B5,-1,0)+1,
OFFSET(B5,-1,0))
```

**Problem**: the above formula works perfectly but I have to drag it down which I’d like to avoid. I’ve tried the approaches below but each returns a “Circular Dependency” error. Is this where something like FLATTEN comes in?

Attempt 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A5:A="-",
OFFSET(B5:B,-1,0)+1,
OFFSET(B5:B,-1,0))
```

Attempt 2:

```
=BYROW(A5:A,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="-",
OFFSET(r,-1,1)+1,
OFFSET(r,-1,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ***starting_date*** is manually given at `Cell_B4`

```
=scan(B4,A5:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="-",a+1,a)))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Just to check my understanding—using SCAN here allows us to put the date in the accumulator, rather than referencing the previous row. And if A = “-“ you increment the accumulator by 1, otherwise you set it to its current value. Is that right? Clever solution and makes me think I’m not using SCAN enough :)

Comment: yep... you got the formula backend working right:

Comment: Appreciate the help—rock on! 
‍